# Unable to log in to Ubuntu running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-14.04

[image]

Recently I created a [Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr) VM in VirtualBox which is running on my Windows 7 laptop. It was working fine, but I am experiencing very strange behavior now. After entering the right password it is again displaying the login screen. But *if* I enter the wrong password then it says the wrong password that is expected. I checked the log file of VirtualBox, but there is nothing.

RAM and HD allocated for VM is sufficient.

Below is the screen again and again appearing after entering the right password to log in.

Comment: any particular reason for using such an ancient version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Sorry for typo, it is 14.04

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me while adding shared folders on VirtualBox. I have removed the shared folders and restarted VirtualBox.

The above steps solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I seems like something is corrupted in your user profile.

You should look into file *~/xsession-errors* for the logs and see what is happening.

#### The usual suspects

Open a terminal screen (Ctrl + Alt + F1) log and and *look* into these file permissions (owner+mode):

- *.cache/*
- *.Xauthority*
- *.ICEauthority*

If nothing works, just delete these files:

- `rm -rf .cache`
- `rm .Xauthority`
- `rm .ICEautority`

Now go back with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, log in and try again.

Another option is to look for any recent changes to the *~/.profile* file if any program you installed has modified it recently.

Comment: I am unable to login so I think I cant see Ubuntu log though I can see VirtualBox log

Comment: Do you have a guest account which you can use to login . Try "guest" username with blank password..

Answer (score 1):

This just happened to me on an [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) guest. I couldn't log in through the GUI, but I was able to log in through the CLI.

[Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) decided to use all the memory in the VM (which somehow prevented a GUI login). I killed Chrome from the CLI and I was then able to login through the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You might have made some changes in `/etc/environment`.

Most probably you have corrupted the PATH variable.

Update the environment file like this (using [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano)):

```
sudo nano /etc/environment

PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Save and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

I recently experienced this issue as well, though with a different Ubuntu OS ([Ubuntu MATE 20.04.2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE#Releases) (Focal Fossa) on Windows 10), but I've seen this happen on [Debian 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_10_(Buster)) (Buster)  and [Debian 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_8_(Jessie)) (Jessie), [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux), and Ubuntu 20.04.2.0.

The inability to login has always been due to insufficient memory allocation (with [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), dynamic allocation doesn't work all the time, and space runs out fast). I received a low drive space warning, but dismissed it; I ended up unable to login to my machine after booting it.

However, you may not receive a warning that you are running low on drive space, so it's a good idea to pay attention to the amount of space you have before running updates or downloading large files. To fix this issue, you'll either need to manually increase the memory allocation from the VirtualBox manager or create a new VM.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using the [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) VM, but I just restarted the VirtualBox and everything works just fine! It might help...

Comment: Re: *"...using the Kali Linux VM"*: Do you mean *"...using Kali Linux in a VM"*? Can you elaborate? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68850429/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).